# All roots of $X^{p^r}-a$ are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that $K$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$ and that $f,g\in K[X]$ such that $f(X)=g(X^{p^r})$ for some $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure of $K$, so we can write $g(X)=\prod_{k=1}^n (X-a_k)$ for some $a_k\in \overline{K}$, therefore $f(X)=\prod_{k=1}^n (X^{p^r}-a_k)$.

All is well by now, however in a book of field theory I've read than choosing some $p^r$-th roots of the $a_k$, say $c_k^{p^r}=a_k$ we have the identity $f(X)=\prod_{k=1}^n (X-c_k)^{p^r}$ as a polinomial in $\overline{K}[X]$, this equality is true and very easy to verify.

My question is the following: over $\overline{K}$ the polynomial $X^{p^r}-a_k$ have $p^r$ roots, and as we can choose any of these $p^r$-th roots to write $f$ as a polynomial over $\overline{K}$ I guess that these $p^r$-th roots cannot be different, otherwise $f$ will be ill-defined as a polynomial over $\overline{K}$. For example suppose that $c$ and $\tilde c$ are two different roots of $X^{p^r}-a$, and that $g(X)=X-a$, then we will had that $f(X)=(X-c)^{p^r}=(X-\tilde c)^{p^r}$ what doesn't make any sense if $c\neq \tilde c$.

Is my reasoning correct? That is, its true that in a field $K$ of characteristic $p>0$ and fixing some algebraic closure $\overline{K}$, some $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and some $a\in \overline{K}$ all roots of the polynomial $X^{p^r}-a$ are equal?

Comment: In $\overline{K}$, the polynomial $X^{p^r}-a_k$ has a root $c_k$ of multiplicity $p^r$, since $X^{p^r}-c_k^{p^r}=(X-c_k)^{p^r}$. I don't know what you mean by "ill-defined" polynomial. I suspect you are conflating polynomial with polynomial function.

Comment: Also, note that if both $c^{p^r}-a=0=d^{p^r}-a$, then $0=c^{p^r}-d^{p^r}=(c-d)^{p^r}$. This implies $c-d=0$.

Comment: @NDB I think you didn't read carefully what I've written, I'm not thinking/talking in any moment about polynomial functions. I'm saying that if $c\neq \tilde c$ then the equality $(X-c)^{p^r}=(X-\tilde c)^{p^r}$ is not possible in $\overline{K}[X]$, so $c=\tilde c$ necessarily if the previous equality is forced by other reasons.

Comment: Your "ill-defined" and your "by other reasons" indicates that you have some misconception about polynomials and polynomial equality. Polynomials are equal, when they are equal. The definition is, when their coefficients are equal. If $X^{p^r}-c^{p^r}=(X-c)^{p^r}=(X-\tilde{c})^{p^r}=X^{p^r}-\tilde{c}^{p^r}$ then $0=c^{p^r}-\tilde{c}^{p^r}=(c-\tilde{c})^{p^r}$. This implies $c=\tilde{c}$.

Comment: @ NDB thank you for clarifying it, you are saying exactly what I said. That $c=\tilde c$ imply that, fixed an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$, all the roots of the polynomial $X^{p^r}-a$ are necessarily equal. This is what I'm trying to confirm from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. $X^{p^r}-a$ has a single root of multiplicity $p^r$ in $\overline{K}$.

Comment: I may be reading too much into your choice of tags, but if $K$ really a finite field, then that only root of $X^{p^r}-a\in K[X]$ is actually an element of $K$ because raising to the $p$th power is a bijection from $K$ to itself. This need not hold when $K$ is not finite.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it was an error, it doesn't need to be a finite field, just a field of positive characteristic. I tend to think that all fields of positive characteristic are finite, but this is wrong. Thank you very much for your comment, I didn't noticed it at all.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57029/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will close my own question with a formal proof.

**Lemma:** let $K$ a field with $\operatorname{char}(K)=p>0$, $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure and $\beta \in \overline{K}$. Then there is a unique $\alpha \in \overline{K}$ such that $\alpha ^p=\beta$.

**Proof:** suppose there are $\alpha,\alpha_1\in \overline{K}$ such that $\alpha ^p=\alpha _1^p=\beta$, then by the binomial theorem we will have that
$$
(X-\alpha )^p=X^p-\alpha ^p=X^p-\beta =X^p-\alpha _1^p=(X-\alpha _1)^p
$$
Therefore $\alpha =\alpha _1$ as $\overline{K}[X]$ is a UFD.∎

Comment: You can also say that for $\alpha \in \overline{K}$ with $\alpha^p = \beta$ it holds that $x^p - \beta = (x - \alpha)^p$ (characteristic $p>0$). Therefore, $\alpha$ is an unique $p$-th root of $\beta$. (In other words, the frobenius map $\overline{K} \to \overline{K}$ that sends $\gamma \mapsto \gamma^p$ is injective in this case.)